# What should I do to correctly display date depending on selected locale?

Tags: ios, swift, date

I use dateFormat "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a". But when I use different Locale, date almost unchanged.

```
let date = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a"

formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")
result = formatter.string(from: date) // 09/10/2019 2:41 PM

formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es_ES")
result = formatter.string(from: date) // 09/10/2019 2:41 p. m.
```

But when I use this dateFormat "MM/dd/yyyy j:mm a" and use it this way 
`formatter.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "MM/dd/yyyy j:mm a", options: 0, locale: Locale(identifier: "de_DE"))`
I have significant changes.

```
formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy j:mm a"
formatter.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "MM/dd/yyyy j:mm a", options: 0, locale: Locale(identifier: "de_DE"))
        result = formatter.string(from: date) // 10.09.2019, 14:41
formatter.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "MM/dd/yyyy j:mm a", options: 0, locale: Locale(identifier: "es_ES"))
        result = formatter.string(from: date) // 10/09/2019 14:41
```

How not to use "j" in date format? What should I do to correctly display date depending on selected locale?

Comment: Why are you using j in format?. What is it's purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From doc: [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1413514-dateformat)

You need to use,

```
formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a"
```

only for fixed format strings. So locale will not have any effect if you are using this. For locale to take effect either you need to use,

```
formatter.dateStyle = .short
formatter.timeStyle = .short
```

methods or as you mentioned,

```
class func dateFormat(fromTemplate tmplate: String, 
              options opts: Int, 
               locale: Locale?) -> String?
```

method. As far as j is concerned I don't see any purpose. You can just use above "dateFormatfromTemplate" method with the same format string.